How to set-up your React Environment
I'm trying to set-up my react environment. When I run npm create-react-app my-app, I get errors. These are the errors below:
npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v20.12.2
npm WARN npm You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we
npm WARN npm can't make any promises that npm will work with this version.
npm WARN npm Supported releases of Node.js are the latest release of 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12.
npm WARN npm You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/
[..................] \ : info using node@v20.12.2
Creating a new React app in C:\Users\Mark\Documents\my-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...        

npm ERR! cb.apply is not a function
[..................] \ : info using node@v20.12.2
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2024-04-27T23_03_13_109Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts has 
failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting my-app / from C:\Users\Mark\Documents2.2
Done.

There shouldn't be any npm errors because I installed the latest node module which includes the corresponding npm version.
Can anyone please help me or guide me in the right direction to setting-up my react environment?
Thanks!

What's your npm version? npm --version

I installed the latest node module which includes the corresponding npm version. Running npm install is only going to install packages that are local to your project, it won't change your global npm version

Nicholas, the npm version is 6.7.0

That's pretty old, and can't be used with your node version. Upgrade npm by running npm install -g npm@latest

Nicholas, I just ran the npm install and I'm getting error messages like npm does not support Node.js v20.12.2 and I should upgrade to a newer version.

Nicholas, it's not upgrading the npm version. What should I do?

It says supported versions  are 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12

Same error message or a different one? If it's the same error message, then it looks like you first need to downgrade your node version to one of the listed ones, then do the upgrade.

This documentation might help https://docs.npmjs.com/downloading-and-installing-node-js-and-npm

I'll try installing an earlier version.  Thanks for your help.

Nicholas, I installed an earlier version of node and I was successful in creating the react app. Then, I got an error message saying that the npm version needs to be updated to version 14 to work with react

I tried updating npm and it just updated to version 6.14

create-react-app is not maintained, and hasn't been maintained for years, please stop using it. It's not even in the React documentation anymore, just read the current docs and pick one of those.

@Mark try "npx create-react-app my-app"

I finally updated node and npm to their latest versions. Now I'm running node versions 22.0.0 and npm version 10.6.0. I created the react app, but when I run npm start to start the node server, I get an error message stating "npm error Missing script: "start". Any suggestions?

As the errors say, this issue is occurring because there is a discrepancy between the versions of Node.js and npm. Although there are different ways to try and solve this, I would first suggest trying to uninstall Node.js and re-installing it. If this fails to work, I would suggest attempting the following steps:

First, we can try to fix this issue by updating npm:

You can do this through your choice of terminal and by running this command:
npm install -g npm@latest

In the case that npm was not updated, this should resolve that issue and update it to the latest version.

If the issue still prevails, we can try fixing it by also updating Node.js to its latest version. This can be done by downloading Node.js through their website which is:
Download Node.js

This should ensure that both Node.js and npm have been updated to their latest versions and thus solve the issue.
Wishing you all the best with resolving this issue.

I updated node and npm to their latest versions. I also created the react-test-app on my local drive. The problem is that there isn't a node module called start to run the node server. It might be deprecated as Mike mentioned. I might just have to read the current docs and follow their guidance. If anyone knows anyway to start-up the node server from the terminal, please advise. Thanks!

I'll like thank all of you for your input. It works perfectly. The step I missed was waiting for "npx create-react-app my-new-app" to fully install. The server is up and running. Thanks!
